# Duvida sobre compactação gzip em servidores IIS

Tags: desempenho, servidor, iis, cache, gzip

Estou com uma dúvida, tenho hospedagem na **kinghost** e antes de acionar o suporte gostaria de saber se o que ocorre é mesmo um problema.

o que acontece é que os arquivos estáticos (principalmente em questão os **css** e **js**) nem sempre estão sendo entregues compactados.

O conteúdo **css** e **js** é entregue com **gzip**, porém nem sempre. Reparei isso ao usar o *pagespeed* do *google* e as vezes ele informar que o conteúdo não está sendo compactado. Então usei o **DevTools** do *chrome* e atualizei várias vezes a mesma página com os mesmos **css** e **js** e notei que realmente o servidor nem sempre entrega esses arquivos compactados.

Por que isso acontece? isso é normal ou uma falha de configuração do servidor?

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

*ps.: caso seja relevante a versão do SO IIS é 8.*

Comment: só para ter certeza, as vezes que ele não entrega compactado o status code é diferente de 304?

Comment: o status é sempre 200

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, o IIS não faz a compactação a cada request. Insira a configuração abaixo no web.config

```
<system.webServer>
        <serverRuntime frequentHitThreshold="1" enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
              <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
              <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="text/xml" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="text/xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
```

Fonte: https://serverfault.com/a/584534

Comment: testei, achei q tinha resolvido, mas voltou a aparecer o mesmo arquivo sem compactar (esporadicamente)